# Does MacRuby support static compilation?

Tags: static, compilation, macruby, macrubyc

Does the latest version of MacRuby support static compilation?

Here's some terminal output from an attempt to use it... It shows up in the options for the macrubyc command.

```
Desktop > macrubyc play_all_podcasts.rb --static -o play_all_podcasts
/usr/local/bin/macrubyc:100:in `initialize': This version of MacRuby does not support static compilation. (ArgumentError)
    from /usr/local/bin/macrubyc:490:in `<main>'
Desktop > macrubyc -v
MacRuby 0.11 (ruby 1.9.2) [universal-darwin10.0, x86_64]
Desktop > macrubyc --help
Usage: macrubyc [options] file...
    -c                               Compile and assemble, but do not link
    -o <file>                        Place the output into <file>
        --static                     Create a standalone static executable
        --framework <name>           Link standalone static executable with given framework
        --sdk <path>                 Use SDK when compiling standalone static executable
        --dylib                      Create a dynamic library
        --compatibility_version <VERSION>
                                     Compatibility Version for linking
        --current_version <VERSION>  Current Version for linking
        --install_name <NAME>        Install Name for linking
    -C                               Compile, assemble and link a loadable object file
    -a, --arch <ARCH>                Compile for specified CPU architecture
    -V, --verbose                    Print every command line executed
    -v, --version                    Display the version
    -h, --help                       Display this information
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've gathered, static compilation is still a work and progress and most likely won't even be included in the 1.0 release.

Comment: Thanks, thats a shame but answers my question